# java & phpseclib, RSA and OAEP?

Tags: java, php, phpseclib

I am encrypting in Java using `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING")` and `setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP)` in phpseclib, but the phpseclib is not decrypting the data correctly.

It worked perfectly when I used `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` in Java, and `setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1)` in phpseclib.

Here are the supported ciphers in Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider

Are none of those ciphers compatible with phpseclib's OAEP implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the size of the keys used, had me puzzled for a while as well.

To use OAEP safely, you have to use >=2048 bit RSA keys.

Also, make sure you run

```
$rsa->setHash('sha512');
$rsa->setMGFHash('sha512');
```

before setEncryptionMode() on the PHP side.

**edit**: it seems 1024 keys won't work correctly even with sha256, so I've modified my answer to only include the safe 2048+ bits route.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to do $rsa->setHash('sha512');  By default sha1 is used.